# How to use Vuelidate in a nested form components hierarchy?

Tags: vue.js, architecture, vuejs3, vuelidate

I'm using Vue 3 and Vuelidate. I'm pretty new to Vue and I would like to create a Page / Form / Input hierarchy of components in which :

- Page will be responsible for holding the model, defining which inputs to use, how fields are validated and the action to execute when the form is valid.
- Form is basically a slot and it will validate all the fields (using Vuelidate) and will emit an event if the form is valid.
- Input displays an input with the data from the model and an error container. (it will later become a dynamic component)

I tried to create this hierarchy but I can't find a way to forward the Vuelidate errors (which is done inside the Form) to the Input.

What am I doing wrong? Is it a structural issue?

This is my implementation of those 3 components :

Page component:

```
<!-- Page.vue -->
<template>
    <Form
        :data="data"
        :validations="validations"
    >
        <Input
            v-model="data.field"
            error="TODO how to pass the error to this field ?"
        ></Input>
    </Form>

    <pre>{{ data }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import Form from "./Form.vue"
import Input from "./Input.vue"
import { required } from '@vuelidate/validators'

export default {

    components: { Form, Input },

    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                field: null,
            },
            validations : {
                field: { required },
            },
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Form component:

```
<!-- Form.vue -->
<template>
    <form
        @submit.stop.prevent="submit"
    >
        <slot></slot>
    </form>

    <pre>{{ v$.$errors }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'

export default {

    setup() {
        return {
            v$: useVuelidate(),
        }
    },

    props: {
        data: {
            required: true,
        },
        validations: {
            required: true,
        },
    },

    validations() {
        return this.validations
    },

    methods: {
        async submit (event) {
            const isValid = await this.v$.$validate()
            console.log(isValid)
        },
    },

}
</script>
```

Input component:

```
<!-- Input.vue -->
<template>
    <input
        type="text"
        v-model="modelLocal"
    >
    <span>{{ error }}</span>
    <pre>{{ modelLocal }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    emits: ['update:modelValue'],

    props: {
        modelValue: {
            required: true,
        },
        error: {
            required: true,
        }
    },

    computed: {

        modelLocal: {
            get() {
                return this.modelValue
            },
            set(value) {
                this.$emit('update:modelValue', value)
            }
        },

    },

}
</script>
```

Comment: If you make Form a dumb component, it's not a good idea to handle Vuelidate inside it

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I was thinking it was a great way to prevent code repetition since I will have lot of forms. In this way, i will not have to setup vuelidate in each form + i will not have to add the submit method in each form with the same validation logic etc..

Comment: I'm not sure you'll save a lot of lines this way. You still can do this but you need to use slot props to pass data from a wrapper to slot comps.

Comment: It seems I found a first solution to my issue. I just posted it. What do you think about it?
Can you tell me more about your solution using slot props? 
Thank you!

Comment: I don't see the obvious problems, besides the fact that you'll have problems with nested forms this way, but it's a corner case. See https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots , it could be something like  `<Form ... v-slot="{ v }">{{v.field.$errors}}`

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to achieve this.
Since i'm not comfortable with Vue, I'm very open to comments and advices about this solution.

In the Form, I provide the vuelidate object but making it reactive using the computed function :

```
<!-- Form.vue -->
setup() {
    return {
        v$: useVuelidate(),
    }
},

provide() {
    return {
        v$: computed(() => this.v$) // NOTE : to make injections reactively linked to the provider, we need to provide a computed property using the computed() function + To make injections automatically unwrap computed refs in Vue < 3.3, we need to set app.config.unwrapInjectedRef to true.
    }
},
```

In this way, in could easily retrieve the vuelidate object (v$) using `inject` in the child component avoiding props drilling.

```
<!-- Input.vue -->
<template>
    <input
        type="text"
        v-model="modelLocal"
    >
    <span>{{ getErrors() }}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    inject: ['v$'],

    emits: ['update:modelValue'],

    props: {
        modelValue: {
            required: true,
        },
        path: {
            required: true,
        },
    },

    computed: {

        modelLocal: {
            get() {
                return this.modelValue
            },
            set(value) {
                this.$emit('update:modelValue', value)
            }
        },

    },

    methods: {
        getErrors(){
            return this.v$.$errors ? this.v$.$errors.filter((item)=> item.$propertyPath === this.path).map(e => e.$message) : ''
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Note that I also added a getErrors() method on the Input and added a prop "path" to know which error I have to retrieve from the vuelidate object.
The input is now called like that:

```
<Input
    v-model="data.field"
    path="data.field"
></Input>
```

Comment: You don't need to mix options and composition. useVuelidate already returns a ref, it would be just `provide('v$', useVuelidate())`

Comment: You are allowed to tick your answer as the correct one.